# Run importing TensorFlow graph fails for uninitialized variables

Tags: tensorflow, javacpp

I'm attempting to run TensorFlow training in java by using `javacpp-presets` for TensorFlow. I've generated a .pb file by using `tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, '.', 'example.pb', as_text=False)` as below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x_data = np.random.rand(100).astype(np.float32)
y_data = x_data * 0.1 + 0.3
Weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], -1.0, 1.0), name='Weights')
biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]), name='biases')
y = Weights * x_data + biases
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - y_data)) #compute the loss
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss, name='train')
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
   print(sess.run(Weights), sess.run(biases))
   tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, '.', 'example.pb', as_text=False)
```

I got:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Attempting to use uninitialized value Weights"

when I run:

```
tensorflow.Status s = session.Run(new StringTensorPairVector(new String[] {}, new Tensor[] {}), new tensorflow.StringVector(), new tensorflow.StringVector("train"), outputs);
```

after loading the graph,`tensorflow.ReadBinaryProto(Env.Default(), "./example.pb", def);`

Is there any `javacpp-presets` api to do the same work as `init = tf.global_variables_initializer()`?
 
Or any C++ TensorFlow api I can use to initialize all variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Python program, `init` (the result of [`tf.global_variables_initializer()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#global_variables_initializer)) is a `tf.Operation` that, when passed to `sess.run()`. If you capture the value of `init.name` when building the Python graph, you can pass that name to `session.Run()` in your Java program before running the training step.

I'm not 100% sure what the API for `javacpp-presets` looks like, but I think you would be able to do this as:

```
tensorflow.Status s = session.Run(
    new StringTensorPairVector(new String[] {}, new Tensor[] {}),
    new tensorflow.StringVector(),
    new tensorflow.StringVector(value_of_init_dot_name),
    outputs);
```

...where `value_of_init_dot_name` is the value of `init.name` you obtained from the Python program.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I fixed this as your answer exactly.